# How does one embed data such as a rating / review from other sites into an App?

Tags: ios, sql, swift, database, web

I am not at all familiar with swift or iOS developmet (I only have python / SQL experience) so I am sorry if this is a stupid question.

**How do iOS developers embed specific data such as a rating or review from other sites into an app that would hypothetically gather this data from several different websites?**

So for example, for video game reviews app, the app wants to have the rating or review number from different sites that are all built and formatted completely differently, how does the iOS dev pull this specific data into a SQL table or into the iOS app itself? I imagine that the iOS app would talk to SQL first, but how does the link between the sites and the back-end environment connect?

**How have you implemented this before, or how have you seen / heard of this being implemented?**

**Can this be done without scraping / hurting SEO?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't access their databases directly.

This can be achieved using the service API or through Web Scraping.

Comment: right I know I don't have access to their db, was wondering how to take data from sites and write it to my own db.

Is there pros / cons to API vs Web Scrape?

Comment: You will need to check if this is legal, you should use API if it's available, web scrapping is a workaround.

Comment: Keep in mind that you may be able to implement your functionalities without storing data, just consuming and interacting with APIs/Web.

Comment: So you are saying it may be illegal to actually store the data you pull from other sites (unless there's an API), but if you were to only consume and present the data and not store it anywhere, then it is generally legal.

Comment: Yes, each website / service has it's own terms, they're most likely crafted for the most common use cases.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your help. Can you recommend any WebScraping tools in case I go that route?

Comment: it will depend a lot on your familiarity with languages, since this question is about swift, you can use webviews and interact with them.

Comment: I see that Python's BeautifulSoup is a good. Python is my go to for sure.

Comment: Ok, check this: https://medium.com/the-andela-way/learn-how-to-scrape-the-web-2a7cc488e017

Comment: And again, since this question is about iOS, you can do it using swift and webviews.

Comment: I think this is enough for this question, if this was helpful remember to mark it as the correct answer to expand it's visibility.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for you help